# Need A Intent-Filter that runs my app when I click on a Buttom in Main Website

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-html

OK. Here is my scenario:

0. Somehow I open `A Payment Gateway` from my `Android App`. (So far So good!)

**Payment Gateway > Android App**

1. Then Depending on how payment interactions turns out for user (whether he pays or cancels) There must be two buttons:

`ACCEPT`-----------------------------`CANCEL`

2. When User Clicks on Cancel I want him to return to app with a `message` like **(FAILED)**
3. When User Clicks on Accept I want him to return to app with a `message` like **(DONE)**

So Based On The `message` I will Show him a page in my app notifying him with more info.

I Know How to Open My app using `<Intent-Filter>` But I want it more Specified!
I Know this That I need a referral link to put it in my `<a href=''> </a> tag` This Link must specify my package name and the activity I'm about to do.

Thank You in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) plugin to deep linking and app linking in flutter :

add this to activity tag in manifest:

```
  <!-- Deep Links -->
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with YOUR_SCHEME://YOUR_HOST -->
    <data
      android:scheme="[YOUR_SCHEME]"
      android:host="[YOUR_HOST]" />
  </intent-filter>
```

then in dart side

```
  Future<void> initUniLinks() async {
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      final initialLink = await getInitialLink();
      // Parse the link and warn the user, if it is not correct,
      // but keep in mind it could be `null`.
      // navigate to every page you want
    } on PlatformException {
      // Handle exception by warning the user their action did not succeed
      // return?
    }
  }
```

then your link can be like this

```
YOUR_SCHEME://YOUR_HOST/status
```

status can be FAILED or DONE